Add multiple members in MS Teams Channel Using Azure Logic App
I am using Azure Logic App to post a message and call to MS Teams. I can add single user in Teams using the Microsoft learn guide. Now I am trying to add multiple users using the same logic.I found one post that it's possible using array object and then looping it but there are no details in there that I know how to use.
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/ece6f0a1-7ca4-498b-be79-edf6c8fc4d82/channels/19%3ALpxShHZZh9utjNcEmUS5aOEP9ASw85OUn05NcWYAhX81%40thread.tacv2/members
Content-type: application/json

{
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
"roles": [],
"user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('jacob@contoso.com')"
}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
I tried to create a Initialize Variable with Array type and value of

[
"user1@mscom"
"user2@mscom"
]

then setting up For Each with variables('ChannelUsers')
and adding

{
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
"roles": [],
"user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('items('For_each')')"
}

but ending up with an error - Action For each must be a parent foreach scope of Scope "Add_Member" to be referenced by repeatItems or Items functions.

When you initialize the array variable, the array items must be separated by commas:

Then use the For each loop over @variables('ChannelUsers'):

Within the loop, you can use the HTTP method with the current item from the For each loop: @{items('For_each')}

Result:


Here's a full code of the (slightly modified) Logic App: https://www.coderstool.com/cs/vJQJ7C

Makes so much sense once you actually see it, thank you
